# Angular5.x progress reporting for long running server process

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, angular5, angular-httpclient

We've run into a repeating design pattern in our django/angular5.x app that's
caused us to write quite a bit of code that directly interacts with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and we wanted to see if anyone had come up with a better solution.

Here's the pattern: Send a request to server which performs a long running operation (let's say 5 minutes). During the operation, the server emits a series of progress reports before responding with success/fail.

For the purpose of this scenario, let's say the server was just emitting a series of progress reports such as the following django/python code:

```
def reports(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(stream())

def stream():
    for num in range(10):
        yield '%d of 10\n' % num
        # simulate random 10 - 30 second delay
        time.sleep(random.randint(10, 30))
```

In Angular5.x we have service to report progress using the observer pattern:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProgressService {
  constructor() { }
  progress() {
    let seen: number = 0;
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 3 || xhr.readyState === 4) {
          observer.next(xhr.responseText.substring(seen);
          seen = xhr.responseText.length;
        }
      }
      xhr.open('POST', '/dosomething', true);
      xhr.send();
    });
  }
}
```

This code works -- but it feels wrong to write something like this each time we interact with a long running service.

We've looked at the angular2 [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) and see it has a `reportProgress` option, but that would only seem to provide [HttpEventType.DownloadProgress](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEventType#DownloadProgress), which does not provide access to the `responseText` seen so far.  I've seen some references to Interceptors, but it's not clear how we'd need to manipulate these to extract the response body accumulated during progress reporting.

Have we run into a limitation of the HttpClient infrastructure -- and we've developed the only viable solution? Or are we missing something blaringly obvious?

Comment: Seems to me you are trying to make http behave in a way like web sockets. So why not use web sockets to do the status reporting?

Comment: websockets on django carries more design overhead than we were looking for, plus requires beefing up the deployment ecosystem (channels + asgi + redis).

Comment: In that case, I think you guys found the proper workaround. I don't see any other viable option. Web Sockets would be the logical option, but in your case due to limitations on the back-end side its not possible.

Comment: Are you uploading or downloading data?

Comment: Check if this could maybe help you (if you want a progress bar): https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-progressbar

Comment: The flow of progress messages is from server to client -- so technically downloading.